# Is this homebrew Oath of the Golden Knight paladin subclass balanced compared to the official subclasses?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, paladin, homebrew-review

> **Oath Spells**
>   You gain Oath Spells at the Paladin levels listed.
>   3 *Hail of Thorns*, *Ensnaring Strike*
>   5 *Locate Animals or Plants*, *Healing Spirit*
>   9 *Conjure Animals*, *Spirit Guardians*
>   13 *Grasping Vine*, *Polymorph*
>   17 *Tree Stride*, *Insect Plague*
>
> **Channel Divinity**
>   When you take this oath at 3rd level, you gain the following Channel Divinity Options:
>
> - **Life Sequester:**
>     Over the course of ten minutes, you transform a small or smaller non-magical object, or a willing creature you are touching into a beast of CR 1/8 or lower, expending a use of channel divinity.  The character's armor and equipment is absorbed into it while it is transformed, and the creature gains no benefit from its armor and equipment.  The character retains the intelligence, wisdom, and charisma scores it had before being transformed.  The character or object returns to their original form after 8 hours or after being reduced to 0 hit-points.  If you transform an object with this feature, the beast it turns into is neutral towards you.
> - **Golden Knight:**
>     As an action, you use your Channel Divinity to summon an Animated Armor that appears in an unoccupied space within 10 feet of you.  The Animated Armor vanishes if it is reduced to 0 hitpoints or if it goes more than 10 feet away from you, or after one minute.  The Animated Armor is friendly to you and your allies and obeys your commands.
>
> **Aura of healing:**
>   At level 7, whenever you cast a paladin spell, you can choose a humanoid ally within 30 feet of you.  They regain hitpoints equal to the level of the spell you cast plus your proficiency bonus.
>
> **Superior Summons:**
>   At level 15, whenever a creature does damage to a creature you have summoned with a paladin spell or Channel Divinity, you can use your reaction to make the attacker take magical bludgeoning damage equal to the damage it dealt (to a maximum of 40 damage).  Once you use this feature you cannot do so until you take a long rest.  Additionally, when you fail a saving throw to maintain concentration on a spell, you can use your channel divinity to attempt the saving throw again instead (you must accept the results of this new roll).
>
> **Field of Futility:**
>   At level 20, as an action you undergo a transformation that lasts for one minute.  While under this transformation you gain the following benefits:
>
> - You can cast *counterspell* as a 3rd level spell at will without expending a spell slot.
> - When you hit a creature with a critical hit, that creature takes an additional 4d10 necrotic and 4d10 psychic damage.
> - You are immune to radiant and necrotic damage.
>
> Once you use this transformation, you cannot use it again until you complete a long rest.

Comment: For Life Sequester, can the creature be any size? Does excess damage past being reduced to 0 HP apply to the creature's original form? For Golden Knight, I assume the Animated Armor disappear any time you and the armor are more than ten feet apart? For Superior Summons, how did you come to the maximum damage of 40? Does the remaking a saving throw apply to any spells and not just summons? For File dof Futility, I assume the additional damage when getting a crit is not then *doubled* by the crit to 8d10 of each?

Comment: I assume that if you turn an object into a creature with Life Sequester it has the base stats for a creature of its type? It does not currently say so, just that it retains the original (non-existent) scores.

Comment: Also, is there any kind of theme/lore for this subclass? The abilities all seem kinda unrelated, but maybe I'm just missing something.

Comment: @Medix2 the creature can be any size, but since there are no CR 0 or 1/8 creatures larger than medium its not really an issue.  Yes, excess damage applies as per the druid rules.  Yes, as it says the Animated Armor disappears. I put a damage cap so that way if a BBEG uses a super powerful attack on a summoned creature he's not instantly defeated.  The saving throw feature is for any spell, hence the "additonally".  For field of futility, the additional damage is added after the crit.

Comment: @Erik, yes it retains its non-existant scores.  A rock would be quite dumb.

Comment: Please explain what the class means and where it draws its power from. Also, the Golden Knight ability is non-scaling for some reason and is garbage at high levels

Comment: @Zobrothian it still is good because it is one more target for enemies to attack instead of you, and it could be ordered to take the Help action and give you advantage, plus Superior Summons gives it a significant power at higher levels

Comment: I assume it's intended that if the animated armor is 10 feet from the Paladin it can be killed by simply shoving it?

Comment: @Medix2 yes____

Answer (score 11):

## In terms of balance

Most of this subclass seems fine, although a few of the features I'd probably buff a little bit, if only because they're otherwise quite difficult to use.

- **Channel Divinity: Golden Knight**. I would revise the wording to *"The Animated Armor vanishes if it is reduced to 0 hitpoints, if it **ends its turn** more than 10 feet away from you, or after one minute."*. Otherwise, it requires very finicky movement tricks to move around the battlefield.

  - Alternatively, if the intent is for the Animated Armor to be leashed to a specific point in space, I would just rewrite it as *"if it ends its turn more than 10 feet away from where it was summoned"*. Either of these would be a lot better for the overall behavior of the creature.
- **Superior Summons**. There's really no good reason to cap the damage at 40 damage. There's already plenty of features in the game that deal retributive damage to a target—see, for example, the Oath of Redemption's *Channel Divinity: Rebuke the Violent*, which at level 3 allows the paladin to do exactly this, without a damage cap, once per use of Channel Divinity, with the only mitigating factor being a Wisdom Save for half damage instead—and there's already at least one feature that allows a PC to immediately deal lethal damage to any creature, mitigated only by a single saving throw—that would be the Way of the Open Hand's *Quivering Palm*, which costs only 3 Ki points (itself a resource that recovers on a Short Rest). So since this feature is already limited by being usable once-per-long-rest, I don't think there's any need to further limit its capabilities in this way.
- **Superior Summons**, *Additional Effect*. I would just make this limited by one use per short rest. Tying this feature to the Channel Divinity feature essentially means you're giving the Paladin 3 Channel Divinity options, breaking the common design convention of only giving a Paladin (or Cleric) 2 Channel Divinity options, and being able to reroll a single concentration save is probably never going to be worth sacrificing your Channel Divinity (or, more likely, withholding their Channel Divinity explicitly for its use), itself already core to most of the rest of the class features.
- **Animated Armor**. Given that this creature is going to be summoned at all levels of play, it might make sense to give it the capacity to scale with the paladin's level. I recommend using the Artificer's Homonculus Servant (Eberron: RftLW, pg. 62) as a template for homebrewing a creature that could be summoned in the place of an *Animated Armor* (you'll probably have to dial the hit points back a bit, maybe more like 3 hit points per level instead of 5).

## In terms of Theme

A lot of those balance issues are pretty minor, in my opinion, and easy to deal with. The bigger issue with this homebrew, in my opinion, is that it's a little bit scattershot in terms of the gameplay style it facilitates. The subclass is called the *Oath of the Golden Knight*, and its Channel Divinity features facilitate summoning creatures, but its Oath Spells list seems to instead be split between nature-themed spells having to do with control (*Ensnaring Strike*, *Grasping Vine*) or summoning, and its level 7 feature (ostensibly replacing the "Aura" most paladin Oaths grant at this level) instead promotes their healing ability. There's a bit of a mismatch between what the features are permitting this Paladin to actually do, and what this Paladin Oath is intended to do.

I would consider revisiting both these features, thinking about a different level 7 feature that would better fit with the other features granted by this class, and thinking about reconsidering the spell list granted to this character, perhaps to focus more on buff spells—spells like *Bless* or *Mantle of the Crusader* would be especially appropriate for this class.

Comment: +1 for the second half of this (I mean, +1 for all of it, but the second half in particular); this was my first thought as well, but you've worded it better than I ever could.

Comment: +1 for the theme mention. Reading through the original post, I still have no idea what the theme is supposed to be behind this paladin, or what it's gameplay group purpose is. It's all over the place and seems to not have any coherent theme.

Comment: Though it should be mentioned that not every class and subclass need a strongly defined theme and/or purpose, because not every individual is completely focused on exactly one purpose, be it by character or training. If a player wants to play a more "scatterbrained" class that has an acceptable power level for its RP, that's fine in my opinion.